# ESP32 point-to-point connection, UART-WIFI passthrough mode, how to configure modules

Tags: wifi, esp32, uart, point-to-point

I try to configure esp32 modules to work in p2p connection. I am trying to use "UART Wi-Fi passthrough transmission when the ESP device works as a softAP in UDP transparent transmission". It is example from datasheet from AT commands firmware. I want to make wireless UART via WiFi, but I do not know how to do it, because the example predicts a situation where we have an ESP-PC connection. I would like one module to send data to another via radio, and the data to be received via the serial port.I am asking for a hint or anything else.

Basic commands sequention for example from datasheet :

```
Set the Wi-Fi mode to softAP.
Command:
AT+CWMODE=2
Response:
OK

Set softAP.
Command:
AT+CWSAP="ESP32_softAP","1234567890",5,3
Response:
OK

Connect the PC to the ESP device softAP.

Create a UDP endpoint.

Use a network tool on PC to create a UDP endpoint. For example, the PC’s IP address is 192.168.4.2 and the port is 8080.

Create a UDP transmission between ESP32 and the PC with a fixed remote IP address and port. The remote host’s IP address is 192.168.4.2, the remote port is 8080, the local port is 2233, and the mode is 0.

Command:

AT+CIPSTART="UDP","192.168.4.2",8080,2233,0
Response:

CONNECT

OK
Enable the UART Wi-Fi transmission mode.

Command:

AT+CIPMODE=1
Response:

OK
Send data in Passthrough Mode.

Command:

AT+CIPSEND
Response:

OK
```

Comment: 1. device: `WiFi softAP` + `WiFiServer`, 2. device: `WiFi station` + `WiFiClient`. This doesn't work?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I should set the first module as softAP and configure it as a TCP / UDP server. Conversely, the second module as STA and configure it as a TCP / UDP client? Will it then be possible to work in the passthrough mode? as UART-WIFI bridge?